# Nested loop through list avoiding same element

Tags: python

I can't explain the concept well at all, but I am trying to loop through a list using a nested loop, and I can't figure out how to avoid them using the same element.

```
list = [1, 2, 2, 4]
for i in list:
    for j in list:
        print(i, j) # But only if they are not the same element
```

So the output should be:

```
1 2
1 2
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 4
2 1
2 2
2 4
4 1
4 2
4 2
```

Edit as the solutions don't work in all scenarios:

The `if i != j` solution only works if all elements in the list are different, I clearly chose a poor example, but I meant same *element* rather than the same number; I have changed the example

Comment: I disagree, I said explicitly asked about them being the same element rather than just the same number, how else would you have worded it?

Comment: @JonathanDyke What if your list is `[2, 2, 2]`. What is the expected output?

Comment: @JonathanDyke I didnot see that you changed the original list too. ;) I apologize.

Comment: @a_guest regardless of the numbers it would be all permutations of ````list[i] list[j]```` except where ````i == j````, so in the case of ````[2, 2, 2]```` it would be ````2 2```` six times

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can compare the indices of the two iterations instead:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 4]
for i, a in enumerate(lst):
    for j, b in enumerate(lst):
        if i != j:
            print(a, b)
```

You can also consider using `itertools.permutations` for your purpose:

```
lst = [1, 2, 2, 4]
from itertools import permutations
for i, j in permutations(lst, 2):
    print(i, j)
```

Both would output:

```
1 2
1 2
1 4
2 1
2 2
2 4
2 1
2 2
2 4
4 1
4 2
4 2
```

Answer (score 3):

Simply:

```
if i != j:
    print(i, j)
```